# Searching for text in html using python

Tags: python, string, search, replace

I have an ebook reader that does not export highlighting annotations into an epub file, so I am to write a [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/about/) plugin to import annotations from the reader and put them into the epub file so that I can read it on my desktop computer.

The naive way of doing this is using the `replace` method on strings in python:

```
for html_id, href in bk.text_iter():
    # read orignal html code from file
    original_html = bk.readfile(html_id)
    # modify html code
    modified_html = original_html.replace('Every issue that comes up', '<span class="highlight">Every issue that comes up</span>')
```

There is a caveat here though: the string I look for might have been continuous text on the ebook reader but could contain html tags in the underlying html file.

I guess it is not me who bumps to this problem first: is there a name and a method for searching with such constraints? It would be useful to get back a list of strings or positions in a file that in all add up to the original text.

Example:

```
<ul>
 <li>Alfa Romeo</li>
 <li>Mercedes</li>
 <li>Volkswagen</li>
</ul>
```

I have highlighted the list in the ebook reader, so I search for

```
Alfa Romeo Mercedes Volkswagen
```

and my search function would return a list with the positions in the html file so that I could add the `span` tags to each.

```
<ul>
 <li><span class="highlight">Alfa Romeo</span></li>
 <li><span class="highlight">Mercedes</span></li>
 <li><span class="highlight">Volkswagen</span></li>
</ul>
```

What is this type of search that allows inserted html tags and whitespace on the way? Is there a library routine for that in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
def highlight(text, keywords, _class='highlight'):
   return re.sub('|'.join(keywords), lambda x:f"<span class='{_class}'>{x.group()}</span>", text)

s = """
<ul>
 <li>Alfa Romeo</li>
 <li>Mercedes</li>
 <li>Volkswagen</li>
</ul>
"""
print(highlight(s, ['Alfa Romeo', 'Mercedes', 'Volkswagen']))
```

Output:

```
<ul>
 <li><span class='highlight'>Alfa Romeo</span></li>
 <li><span class='highlight'>Mercedes</span></li>
 <li><span class='highlight'>Volkswagen</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is the substitution that I would do _after_ the search.